# Laravel withcount

Tags: php, laravel

I need to count orderpassenger with withcount

```
$orders = $this->orderRepository
              ->search($filters, true)
              ->sort($sort)
              ->select([
                'id',
                'code',
                'pro_periods_id',
                'quantity_adult_single',
                'quantity_adult_double',
                'quantity_adult_triple',
                'quantity_child_bed',
                'quantity_child_no_bed',
                'quantity_infant',
                'created_at',
                'created_by'
              ])
              ->with(['orderPassengers' => function($sub_query){
                  $sub_query->select([
                    'id',
                    'pro_orders_id',
                    'pro_rooms_id',
                    'title_name',
                    'first_name_en',
                    'last_name_en',
                    'birth_date'
                  ])
                  ->with(['room' => function($sub_query){
                    $sub_query->select([
                      'id',
                      'pro_periods_id',
                      'room_number',
                      'room_type',
                      'extra_bed'
                    ]);
                  }]);
              }])
              ->withCount('orderPassengers');
```

This my result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh8Zd.png)

I get nothing with withcount.

How can I get orderPassenger_count.

Comment: How do you execute the query? With `->get()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$orders = $this->orderRepository
          ->search($filters, true)
          ->sort($sort)
          ->select([
            'id',
            'code',
            'pro_periods_id',
            'quantity_adult_single',
            'quantity_adult_double',
            'quantity_adult_triple',
            'quantity_child_bed',
            'quantity_child_no_bed',
            'quantity_infant',
            'created_at',
            'created_by'
          ])
          ->withCount(['orderPassengers' => function($sub_query){
              $sub_query->select([
                'id',
                'pro_orders_id',
                'pro_rooms_id',
                'title_name',
                'first_name_en',
                'last_name_en',
                'birth_date'
              ])
              ->with(['room' => function($sub_query){
                $sub_query->select([
                  'id',
                  'pro_periods_id',
                  'room_number',
                  'room_type',
                  'extra_bed'
                ]);
              }]);
          }]);
```

Comment: I got nothing in order.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$orders = $this->orderRepository
          ->search($filters, true)
          ->sort($sort)
          ->select([
            'id',
            'code',
            'pro_periods_id',
            'quantity_adult_single',
            'quantity_adult_double',
            'quantity_adult_triple',
            'quantity_child_bed',
            'quantity_child_no_bed',
            'quantity_infant',
            'created_at',
            'created_by'
          ])
          ->withCount(['orderPassengers' => function($sub_query){
              $sub_query->select([
                'id',
                'pro_orders_id',
                'pro_rooms_id',
                'title_name',
                'first_name_en',
                'last_name_en',
                'birth_date'
              ])
              ->with(['room' => function($sub_query){
                $sub_query->select([
                  'id',
                  'pro_periods_id',
                  'room_number',
                  'room_type',
                  'extra_bed'
                ]);
              }]);
          }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a `withCount()` on a defined relation of the model.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    function orderPassengers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\orderPassengers');
    }
}
```